# Print column values to rows of new data frame only if it matches second dataframe range in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames and I'd like to print from a column in df1 to separate rows of a new df/matrix if values match a range around df2. Please see example below.

df1

```
Chr Coord  Value
1     25     10
1     75     20
1     125    15
1     175    30
2     25     16
2     75     25
2     125    50
2     175    100
2     225    150
```

df2

```
Chr Coord
1    75
2    125
```

What I need is if:

```
(df1$Chr == df2$Chr & df1$Coord <= df$2Coord +50 & df1$Coord is >= df2$coord -50)
```

then print

```
df1$Value to it's own row of a new data frame or matrix.
```

Final output that I need is:

df3

```
10   20   15
25   50   100
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but it looks like you're working with genetic ranges (assuming `Chr` = Chromosome). If so, you should look at the [GenomicRanges](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package from Bioconductor. It provides classes for representing ranged data with biological metadata and includes methods for subsetting one set of ranges based on their overlap with another set of ranges.

First you need to convert your data.frames to `GRanges` objects:

```
library(GenomicRanges)

gr1 <- GRanges(seqnames = df1$Chr, 
               IRanges(start = df1$Coord, width = 1),
               Value = df1$Value)

gr2 <- GRanges(seqnames = df2$Chr, 
               IRanges(start = df2$Coord, width = 1),
               Value = df2$Value)
```

Then use `subsetByOverlaps()` with the `maxgap` argument to indicate we're looking for ranges within 50:

```
df3 <- subsetByOverlaps(gr1, gr2, maxgap = 50)
```

Extract the `Value` column of `df3`:

```
df3$Value
```

Final output:

```
## 10  20  15  25  50 100
```

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful. This gets me 90% of the way there. Only thing left that I need to do is split the final output from:
10 20 15 25 50 100
into 2 rows with the first three numbers in the first and the last three in the second. If df2 has an additional column ex. Names can I add this as an additional column to the subset output. I was able to add additional columns from df1.

Comment: I added an additional identifying column (ex. Names) with a merge function. Now it should be easily to split by name.